# Iran and the point four program and the mutual defense act of 1949?

Tags: united-states, iran

What were the US's and Iran's terms in these agreements? What was the total amount of aid Iran recieved from the US during this time?

Comment: Have you done any preliminary research?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there aren't many documents talking specifically about Iran :(